# Start uWAmp in Silent mode

Tags: uwamp

I need to start uwamp before My user can use an app. But I would need to start Uwamp in silent mode i.e without getting the window on the screen. Is there any config I didn't find it

Answer (score 0):

So stupid I am... Prefrences and set it ip to start in systray mode....